# Insert timestamp in HREF

Tags: javascript

I have to include a timstamp in an HREF link. I can only use only one inliner such as the following:

```
<A HREF="https://ad.doubleclick.net;ord=javascript:time();">
```

I can see that the time() function is not translated on the link, when the page is displayed. I'd need something like:

```
<A HREF="https://ad.doubleclick.net;ord=1471189126">
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `href` through JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript to set the href:

```
document.getElementById('idOfAnchor').href = "https://ad.doubleclick.net;ord=" + time();
```

Comment: If she's doing this on multiple elements and just adding the timestamp dynamically, `document.getElementById('idOfAnchor').href += time();` might be a better approach.